# Haskell: 'tell ["abc"]' evaluation throwing "non-type variable argument" error

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

When I attempt to evaluate `tell ["abc"]` in GHCI, it spits out this error:

```
Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: MonadWriter [[Char]] m
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
```

If I do `tell ["abc"] :: Writer [String] ()`, it evalutes without a problem, but why is that necessary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tell`'s return type is more general than `Writer`: it uses [the `MonadWriter` type class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Class.html#t:MonadWriter) to abstract over all monads with a writerly spirit.

```
tell :: MonadWriter w m => w -> m ()
```

So when you write `tell ["abc"]` with no type annotation, the type-checker unifies `w` with `[String]` but it doesn't have any information with which to refine `m`. So you get

```
tell ["abc"] :: MonadWriter [String] m => m ()
```

Haskell 98 doesn't support constraints like `MonadWriter` applied to concrete type arguments like `[String]`, so the above is not valid Haskell 98. Turning on [the `FlexibleContexts` language extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#the-context-of-a-type-signature) enables support for this sort of type.

Since `Writer w` is an instance of `MonadWriter w` (when `w` is an instance of `Monoid`), `tell`'s principal type can be specialised to `Writer`. That's why it worked when you gave it the `Writer` type annotation.

```
tell :: w -> Writer w ()
```

Comment: In this scenario, is `m ()` the concrete type? What tells the compiler that that m has a kind of `(* -> *)` instead of `(* -> * -> *)`?

Comment: Also, could you clarify what you mean by "principal type"?

Comment: In no particular order: 1) "Principal type" is just another way of saying "most general type". 2) The invalid part of the type signature is `MonadWriter [String] m`; `[String]` is a concrete type, not a type variable, and Haskell 98 requires constraints' arguments to always be type variables. 3) The type-checker knows `m :: * -> *` because a) it's applied to one argument in the type expression `m ()` and b) it's used as the second argument to `MonadWriter :: * -> (* -> *) -> Constraint`